# How to change caption of drilldown button at the top right of sunburst chart in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Can anyone tell me how to change caption of drilldown button at the top right of sunburst chart in highcharts? Please look at the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L955C.png) attached.

Comment: See [lang.drillUpText](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang.drillUpText)

Comment: @morganfree I tried but did not work. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer by looking at the source code of sunburst.js.

```
series: [{
    type: "sunburst",
    data: data,
    allowDrillToNode: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    drillUpButton: {
       text: "< Back"
  }
}}
```

`drillUpButton` property changes the text of the drill up button in Sunburst chart in highcharts.